# Need Explanation to compute beauty of string

Tags: algorithm

[Here](https://www.facebook.com/hackercup/problems.php?pid=475986555798659&round=185564241586420) is a link of a Problem.

As per the problem statement it is clear that beauty of a string is sum of its letters.

And From *The beauty of each letter is an integer between 1 and 26, inclusive, and no two letters have the same beauty*

According to that how can I assume the beauty of a letter.

How did they compute beauty of "**ABbCcc**" as 152?

*I Do not need  Solution of the Problem, I just need an explanation for the given output.*

Any of Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: I can't read the problem because I'm not signed up.

Comment: The task is not public........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the beauty for letter c is 26, b is 25 and a is 24

total=24+25*2+26*3=152

Comment: but how did they compute beauty of letter, I can not figure it out

Comment: would you highlight that sentence please

Comment: I've read the problem, but I'm not able to figure it out.. Would you edit that statement in your answer Please :)

Comment: does it mean the number with high frequency in string will have the highest as 26 beauty and number with second highest would have 25 and so on...??